# Basic authentication with StageWebView

Tags: apache-flex

Is there a way to perform basic authentication using StageWebView on mobile devices in Flex?
The problem is that mobile (iOS, Android) implementations don't provide authentication dialog and documentation about this is pretty unclear.

On this link:
http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/stagewebview-differences-platforms-air-sdk.html
it's suggested to use URLRequest as a workaround, but I already have URLLoader that successfully authenticates and loads data from the same service and it doesn't affect StageWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.  The problem is after authentication (after the app install page through facebook), it goes blank.  I at least found that the url is "m.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request" and then continues with a massive amount of get variables.

From my research, I believe this is a pop-up window that runs an auto-close function but doesn't seem to work in Adobe AIR.  I've tried running a TimerEvent in a "LocationChangeEvent" to nav back (have to run 2 back to back because the webViewObject.historyBack() method does not support parameters), and this works but only after the app has been installed on their facebook account successfully which in turn affects the ability to even install it to their Facebook in the first place.

I also tested reading the url to trigger callbacks but the one major problem is the "Install" page and the "login successful" page have the EXACT same url entirely, at least from start to finish.  Haven't tested the title yet due to my frustrations lol...working on that.

If anyone has any suggestions, this would be supremely helpful and seriously appreciated!